# Timezone related issue in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two server in two different time zones.One is in India and another one is in USA. 
I have one mysql query in which I am comparing the user's shift time to the current time.. 
There is same data available on both the servers.
But in India, current time is different and in USA it is different. SO I am getting different results.
There is any way that how can I get same values on both timezone's server.

Please Help

Comment: This is why we store all the data as UTC in databases, or if you will - in a `timestamp` type. If you didn't do that, you're screwed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the timezone of one of the servers so that they are both the same?

Comment: Not any other way by mysql query?

Comment: Got it.. 
I have done like this at the time of DB Connection so it wont reflect for whole server: 
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+00:00';
Thanks